# the best way to make a big file with jQuery or Java

Tags: java, jquery, csv, file, xls

I am developing a web app in jQuery and Java. I have the task of making a report with some database records. The report must be able to be downloaded in csv, xls and txt format. The number of records of the file are variable, but some times are too big, like ten million of records.

I have two questions:

- First: what is the best option to make the big file, Java or jQuery?
- Second: can you give me an example of the implementation?

I currently have the implementation of the report in csv format in jQuery, and it works well, the detail is that when the report has more records than 800,000, the memory of the browser ends and ends in error. do you know some way to fix it?

This is the code:

```
$("#btnSaveReporte").on(
            'click',
            function(event) {
                getValuesSelected();
                var valiFec = validarFechasEnUso();
                if (validarFechasEnUso()) {

                    if (validarCampos()){
                        // get data report
                        $.ajax({
                            type : "POST",
                            url : "/VentasB/api/getDataReport",
                            data : {
                                fechaIni : fechaIni,
                                fechaFin : fechaFin,
                                orgVentas : Object.keys(orgVentas).join(',').replace(/'/g, ""),
                                canalDist : Object.keys(canalDist).join(','),
                            //canalDist : "'10','11','12'",
                                sector : Object.keys(sector).join(',').replace(/'/g, ""),
                                ofiVentas : $.map(ofiVentas, function(obj) { return "'" + obj.value + "'" }).join(','),
                            },
                            success : function(result) {
                                console.log(result);
                                
                                if(result.data.length > 0){
                                    // CSV
                                    var fileName = "Reporte_Ventas_" + fechaIni
                                            + "_to_" + fechaFin + ".csv";
                                    exportDataToCSV(result.data, fileName,
                                            "#reportFile");
                                    // trigger de click para descargar automaticamente el reporte
                                    
                                    $("#reportFile")[0].click();
                                }else{
                                    Swal.fire({
                                        icon : 'info',
                                        title : 'Sin resultados',
                                        text : 'no se econtró ningún registro que cumpla con los parametros de busqueda.'
                                    })
                                }

                            }
                        });
                    }

                } else {
                    // swal error

                }
            });

// ******************** funcion para descargar csv *********************
function exportDataToCSV(data, title, btnContainer) {
    var csv = ""

    for (var g = 0; g < data.length; g++) {
        // for(var g=0; g < 100; g++){
        // console.log("entro data")
        // console.log(data[g])
        if (g == 0) {

            csv += "bill_stmnt_id, distributor_id, bill_type_cd, bill_stmnt_base_id, eff_dt, eff_tm, bill_distrib_channel_cd,"
                    + "total_charge_amt, total_tax_amt, subtotal_amt, discounts, bill_equipment_deposit, price, perc_fin, amt_fin,"
                    + "bill_rfc_ini, bill_customer_cd, bill_shop_cd, bill_shop_name,bill_shop_id, bill_org_name, bill_address,"
                    + "bill_move_type_cd, bill_payment_condition_cd, region_id, bill_customer_group_cd, bill_customer_group_desc,"
                    + "bill_user_id, bill_sale_force_desc, bill_sale_reason_cd, bill_rfc_end, bill_source_type_cd";
            csv += "\n";
        }

        csv += '"' + data[g].bill_stmnt_id + '",';
        csv += '"' + data[g].distributor_id + '",';
        csv += '"' + data[g].bill_type_cd + '",';
        csv += '"' + data[g].bill_stmnt_base_id + '",';
        csv += '"' + data[g].eff_dt + '",';
        csv += '"' + data[g].eff_tm + '",';
        csv += '"' + data[g].bill_distrib_channel_cd + '",';
        csv += '"' + data[g].total_charge_amt + '",';
        csv += '"' + data[g].total_tax_amt + '",';
        csv += '"' + data[g].subtotal_amt + '",';
        csv += '"' + data[g].discounts + '",';
        csv += '"' + data[g].bill_equipment_deposit + '",';
        csv += '"' + data[g].price + '",';
        csv += '"' + data[g].perc_fin + '",';
        csv += '"' + data[g].amt_fin + '",';
        csv += '"' + data[g].bill_rfc_ini + '",';
        csv += '"' + data[g].bill_customer_cd + '",';
        csv += '"' + data[g].bill_shop_cd + '",';
        csv += '"' + data[g].bill_shop_name + '",';
        csv += '"' + data[g].bill_shop_id + '",';
        csv += '"' + data[g].bill_org_name + '",';
        csv += '"' + data[g].bill_address + '",';
        csv += '"' + data[g].bill_move_type_cd + '",';
        csv += '"' + data[g].bill_payment_condition_cd + '",';
        csv += '"' + data[g].region_id + '",';
        csv += '"' + data[g].bill_customer_group_cd + '",';
        csv += '"' + data[g].bill_customer_group_desc + '",';
        csv += '"' + data[g].bill_user_id + '",';
        csv += '"' + data[g].bill_sale_force_desc + '",';
        csv += '"' + data[g].bill_sale_reason_cd + '",';
        csv += '"' + data[g].bill_rfc_end + '",';
        csv += '"' + data[g].bill_source_type_cd + '",';

        // csv += "hola" + "," ;

        csv += "\n";
    }
    // Deliberate 'false', see comment below
    if (false && window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {
        console.log("entro 1")
        var blob = new Blob([ decodeURIComponent(csv) ], {
            type : 'text/csv;charset=utf8'
        });

        // Crashes in IE 10, IE 11 and Microsoft Edge
        // See MS Edge Issue #10396033
        // Hence, the deliberate 'false'
        // This is here just for completeness
        // Remove the 'false' at your own risk
        window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, title);

    } else if (window.Blob && window.URL) {
        console.log("entro 2")
        // HTML5 Blob
        var blob = new Blob([ csv ], {
            type : 'text/csv;charset=utf-8'
        });
        var csvUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

        $(btnContainer).attr({
            'download' : title,
            'href' : csvUrl
        });
    } else {
        console.log("entro 3")
        // Data URI
        var csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,'
                + encodeURIComponent(csv);

        $(btnContainer).attr({
            'download' : title,
            'href' : csvData,
            'target' : '_blank'
        });
    }
}
```

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I see no reason for this question to have the `makefile` tag.

Comment: Hi, I added the makefile tag to it because the purpose of the program is to generate a file in csv, txt and xls format.

Comment: Makefiles are control files for the POSIX `make` program specifically... the `makefile` tag isn't a general tag to be applied any time you're asking a question about trying to create a file of any format, FYI.  Only if you're trying to write a makefile.  Cheers!

Comment: Now I understand, I will remove it, thank you

Comment: Thanks, good luck with your question!  Sorry I don't know anything about it :( :)

Answer (score 1):

With a large file, you do not want to build it in memory and then download it, because as you have seen, you will run out of memory. The ideal workflow is to build it just as it is being downloaded, so that the portion you need to memorize is minimal.

#### The Java way

Since you are building a web application in Java, you are probably using a framework, instead of implementing an HTTP server by yourself. The libraries you are using probably have support for serving something big as it is being requested, while the rest of the application can continue working (streaming). The best approach is to use this functionality.

For example, if you were using Spring MVC, I would implement downloading of a big file as follows:

```
@GetMapping(value="/file/{id}")
public StreamingResponseBody getBigFile(@PathVariable long id) throws IOException {     
    File f = /* find the file here, for example using id*/;
    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
    return new StreamingResponseBody() {
        @Override
        public void writeTo(OutputStream os) throws IOException {
            FileCopyUtils.copy(in, os);
        }
    };
}
```

You can go one step further, and actually write to the stream only as it gets written; that way, you do not have to store the big file locally before you send it on.

### The Javascript way

[Webworkers + fetch + stream api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39682465/javascript-writing-to-download-stream) may be able to help you to stream data into a file without storing it into memory. I have never tried this, and am happily surprised that it seems to be possible. Beware that not all browsers will support the necessary web APIs

### The takeaway

Avoid unnecessary copies, and stream instead of buffering whenever possible. It saves a lot of memory, and also avoids doing work before it will be needed.