# How to get downlaod progress with fetch()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

In JavaScript I am using `fetch()` to download large files.

Is there a way to get a download progress indicator while using `fetch()`, like a percentage or number of bytes downloaded?

Comment: Since `fetch` returns a promise, I doubt it. Promises don't have any concept of progress.

Comment: Duplicate? [Progress indicators for fetch?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35711724/218196) . [This answer talks about downloads](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35712094/218196).

Comment: The answer seems outdated, and not working.

Comment: @RaedCHAMMAM _"Is there a way to get a download progress indicator while using `fetch()`, like a percentage or number of bytes downloaded?"_ Yes. Use `Response.body.getReader()`, `TextDecoder`. See [How to solve Uncaught RangeError when download large size json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39959467/how-to-solve-uncaught-rangeerror-when-download-large-size-json)

Comment: @RaedCHAMMAM Does the linked Answer resolve present Question?

Comment: @FelixKling _"Since fetch returns a promise, I doubt it. Promises don't have any concept of progress."_ `Response.body` has a `.getReader()` method that returns a `ReadableStream` which can be utilized to read the bytes of  `Response.body` as a stream. Together with `TextDecoder`, it is possible to read the progress of `Response.body` as the stream is occurring.

Comment: @guest271314: yep, I learned about it from the other question. I'm still right about the promise part though ;)