# Continually send and receive AJAX response while previous request is pending

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am running a Python script in a Node.js framework, and it takes 30 seconds to finish. While waiting for the script to be finished, I want to show the progress on the page. Script generates 7 files, so I want to show the number of files in directory.

First, I am sending an AJAX request to the page that will run the Python script:

```
var isFinished = false;
$.ajax({
    url: "/process/xlsx/" + uuid,
    type: "GET",
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.status == "success") {
            $("#infoText").text("finished");
            isFinished = true;
        } else {
            $("#infoText").text("failed");
        }
    }
});
```

Since AJAX is asynchronous and the browser will run the next line without waiting for the first AJAX request to finish, I am sending another request whose response will be the number of files in the directory. Below code works without any problems normally (when I do not send the first request).

```
while (!isFinished) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/process/" + uuid + "/phase",
        type: "GET",
        timeout: 1000,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.status == "success") {
                var numberOfFiles = data.numberOfFiles;
                $("#infoNumber").text(numberOfFiles);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I know I am doing something wrong because I don't know much about AJAX. Is there anyway to fix this problem?

Comment: What is purpose of `while` loop?

Comment: can you post the code that execute the python process?
You have also have problem in the while, you have to use interval.. it will be better.

Comment: @guest271314, I guess it's continuously check the progress.

Comment: yes but it will sent a lot of requests, I think that interval of 200 milisec will be ok..

Comment: I didn't get what and where was the error.

Comment: @Alon, yes, or just wait for the previuos request finish.

Comment: @MateusPires I think that he has an error in the nodejs that he execute the python and block everything.. so the server will not response to the the second request.

Comment: You could display an image or text notifying process is pending during the procedure. Alternatively, you could utilize `WebSocket` to send data from server. Though why create two procedures; one sending and receiving data constantly, the other processes a substantial amount of data; if user is aware the procedure will take n time to complete?

Comment: @Alon, yess, I thought this too. It's something that he could realize when the first request finish. But there's no nodejs code to help :/

Comment: A possible alternative approach would be to read bytes of the downloading file [How to solve Uncaught RangeError when download large size json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39959467/how-to-solve-uncaught-rangeerror-when-download-large-size-json).

Comment: you could set `async : false` and show the ajax loading screen while it is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it using intervals.

```
var isFinished = false;

// run python script
$.ajax({
    url: "/process/xlsx/" + uuid,
    type: "GET",
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.status == "success") {
            $("#numbersNum").text("finished");
            isFinished = true;
        } else {
            $("#numbersNum").text("failed");
        }
    }
});

var checkDirectory = function () {
    if (isFinished) {
        clearInterval(checkDirectoryInterval);
        return;
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: "/process/" + uuid + "/phase",
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.status == "success") {
                var numbersNum = data.numberOfFiles;
                $("#numbersNum").text(numbersNum);
            }
        }
    });
};

var interval = 2000;

var checkDirectoryInterval = setInterval(checkDirectory, interval);
```