# Chart.Js lagging: is there any open source tool for handling 80 million values?

Tags: javascript, charts, bigdata, chart.js

I have been using Chart.Js for drawing charts. The problem is that it lags too much when I load it with lots of data (100 thousand values, for example). And depending on the file I am analysing, I might have about 80 million values to handle.

Is there any open source and no watermark option available? Or even a way of making Chart.Js handles this huge amount of data?

PS: the idea is to draw that qty. of data in a webpage. Not in a desktop app.

Comment: Could you pre-aggregate the data on the server side?

Comment: What is the total size in MB/GB of the data? The issue is not handling the data, the issue is the available disk space and RAM of the computers used to handle the data, which could vary considerably.

Comment: See [How to solve Uncaught RangeError when download large size json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39959467/)

Comment: @JSmith, as far as I have noticed, I will probably have to go that way.

Comment: @guest271314 I am not having the mentioned error. And the files may vary from 200MB to 5GB, for example. I think I will have to leave the whole data for the server and draw shorter samples of it.

Comment: @JulioSouto depends what you're doing with the data really but as two rules of thumb; make the server do all the grunt-work in terms of aggregation, and 'page' the data into smaller subsets :)

Comment: @JSmith it is mostly already on the server side, but not all the calculation (distributions/averages, models, etc), so I will have to put all of them in the backend and load in HTML and Javascript strictly the data being analysed in that specific moment. Thanks for the hint :)

Comment: @JulioSouto that sounds like exactly the right approach - good luck :)